# Metodo para recorrer datos de un json y ver cuantos nombres duplicados hay con Python

Tags: python, json

Hola estoy trabado con un ejercicio para la secundaria... a ver si alguien me podrá ayudar?

Tengo este archivo `.json`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 3,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
{
        "id": 4,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 5,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Maria"
    }
]
```

Necesito crear una clase en `python` con un constructor y un método que pueda decir cuales nombres repetidos hay y cuantos con un `print`

Es muy complicado no me sale... sé como se crea una clase y como un constructor en python pero no se como empezar para crear un metodo que lea ese archivo json y me diga cuales nombres repetidos hay y cuantos

Alguien me podrá ayudar como empezar a armar el metodo? asi me voy guiando y aprendiendo porque no estoy pudiendo encontrar esto por internet.

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Es desmotivante entrar en una publicación con la intención de ayudar y ver que el usuario no ha mostrado que ha investigado o intentado algo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que recibes, o en su defecto mostrar lo que has investigado. El objetivo de este sitio es ayudar a las personas que muestran un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si la solicitud es del tipo alguien hágalo por mi, tal vez un sitio de `freelance` sea mejor opción.

Answer (score 0):

te doy una idea de la solución:

1 -> Decodificar el Json
2 -> Recorrer el json con la llave nombre para contar todos los nombres y guardarlos en la estructura de control _dic.
3 -> Ver en la estructura de control que nombre está más de 1 vez... esos son los repetidos.

```
json = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 3,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
{
        "id": 4,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 5,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Maria"
    }
]

#Guardar los nombres en un diccionario para control de repetidos
_dic = {} # {'nombre:str', qty:int}
# Recorrer el Json con un for
for i in json:
    # si no esta creelo
    if i['nombre'] not in _dic.keys():
        _dic[i['nombre']] = 0
    # Aumentar el contador
    _dic[i['nombre']] = _dic[i['nombre']] + 1

# Recorrer nuevamente la estructura de control para saber repetidos
for i in _dic:
    if _dic[i] > 1:
        print(f"El nombre: {i} se encuentra repetido {_dic[i]} veces")
```